# Can we use Google Maps Polyline values to draw or render the navigation line on an empty canvas or file?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Navigation based application, and I want to know the path of the particular direction set in form of a Drawing.

So my question is, Can we use the Google Maps Polyline value to draw the same line it draws on the map, onto an empty canvas?

The document I am referring is: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

(It is mentioned here that polyline use lat,lng value to render these lines over map)

If not polyline, can you suggest me any other around?